# how to auto-generate a report with JasperReports

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jasper-reports, auto-generate

I'm working on NetBeans, and want to 'auto-generate' a report with JasperReports.

Here is the deal: I want to create a form that asks for a date frame in order to do a sql query and bring that information; then format it and generate a PDF report out of it.

I see that JasperReports uses the jrxml files compiled to .jasper in order to generate the reports.  I want to know if that jrxml could be auto-generated by some code of the API, or it would be needed to edit the jrxml file 'programatically' to auto-generate the report.

Thanks,
gadget00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/). It allows you to programmatically create reports without a jrxml file.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, pdfFileName);
```

it works perfectly.